# Searching a file and returning a list of just function names using regex

Tags: python, regex

So I have files of code that contains functions and I need to design a function that will teach through each line of the code and return a list that captures just the function names of the functions in the file. For example, the first file looks like this:

```
def this_is_a_function():
    return 20

def fun():
    return 'this is fun!'
```

Using my function, I should have a list that if printed should return this:

```
this_is_a_function
fun
```

Here is the code I have been using:

```
import re

def get_func_names(filename):
    """doc"""
    infile = open(filename)
    data = infile.readlines()    
    result = []
    for line in data:
        matching = re.search(r'\s*def (\w+)', line)
        if matching != None:
            result += matching.group(1)
    return result
```

and it does capture all the letters correctly but they are all printed separately rather than as a whole function name like this (this is a printed and sorted version of result):

```
_
_
_
a
c
f
f
h
i
i
i
n
n
n
o
s
s
t
t
u
u
```

Is there something I can change about my regex that will capture the name as a while and not each letter and/or underscore....

Answer (score 1):

`a += b` when applied to something iterable works like `a.extend(b)`, which adds every element of `b` to `a`.

As strings are iterable, when using `+=` Python is taking each element of the string and adding it to the list. Instead, use `result.append(matching.group(1))`.